# spellcheck preloaded text of richEditControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, spell-checking, richedit

I'm using the devex richEditControl to allow my user to type and format the text  etc in a winforms control. I set the spell checker to the AsYouType mode which is working correctly as I type in my richEditControl. As I had in mind, the spell checker underlines any spelling mistakes as I type.

I'm running into a problem when I try to do the following - 
Load the richEditControl and set the htmlText to html that I load from the database. I need these spelling mistakes underlined. The only partial lead I was able to find is to call `spellChecker.Check()`. I tried doing `spellChecker.Check(richEditControl)` and I tried `spellChecker.Check(richEditControl.htmlText)`, I get a popup that spell check is complete, but I'm not getting my mistakes underlined. I don't want any popup, I just want the control to load with mistakes underlined.

Can somebody pls assist? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the only lead I can find is this:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q318435

but I can't get this to work